# Delete image thats stored in NSSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

Im trying to give user option to delete an image picked from camera that is then saved in `NSUserDefaults`, then passed to another view.  I cant seem to keep the image deleted.  It deletes the image initially but still puts the original picked image on the other view its passed to  and re appears on reload of the view.

Do I need to do something with the reading out of my `NSUserDefaults` method in `viewDidLoad`?  I tried an `if` statement to only read out the `NSUserDefaults` method in `viewDidLoad` if `myPicture` was `!=nil` but still got the same behaviour

viewDIdLoad:

```
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([prefs objectForKey:@"image2"]) {

        NSData *imgData = [prefs objectForKey:@"image2"];
        self.engineersPicture.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imgData];
    }
```

Get image and save to NSUserDefaults:

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
DebugLog(@"info dict: %@", info);
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
self.engineersPicture.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.engineersPicture.image = image;
NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5f);
NSString *path2 = [ICUtils pathForDocument:@"engineersPicture.png"];
[imageData2 writeToFile:path2 atomically:NO];



NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:imageData2 forKey:@"image2"];
[prefs synchronize];
self.engineersPicture.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData2];

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Delete Image:

```
- (IBAction)deletePicture:(id)sender {

self.myPicture.image = nil;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"image2"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize ];

}
```

Comment: How do you "reload" the view?

Comment: When I say reload I mean when a new viewController is presented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it

```
 - (IBAction)deletePicture:(id)sender {
 self.engineersPicture.image  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"user.png"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"image2"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize ];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"user.png"];
NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5f);
NSString *path2 = [ICUtils pathForDocument:@"engineersPicture.png"];
[imageData2 writeToFile:path2 atomically:NO];
}
```